# Spring boot job execution delayed with the annotation @scheduled

Tags: spring, cron

I'm trying to execute a job with this schedule:

@Scheduled(cron = "0 2 * * * ?")

At second :00 of minute :02 of every hour

But the execution of the job is delayed at 01:02am it occurs at 01:58am without any reason..

Do you have an idea ? Is it related to the cron expression ?

Please see attached the logs of my job:

[image: Job logs]